# Dynamic typedef of a primitive in C++

Tags: c++, physics, typedef

I am making a toy physics engine which works with floating point numbers which I call reals.

At present, I am using a typedef;

```
typedef float real;
```

This is so I can change the precision of the floating point values to doubles or long doubles, but obviously I have to recompile. I would like to be able to cleanly define the type of real at runtime, so that I can specify the precision via command-line or an intialization GUI interface.

I know typedef is determined at compile time, so I am wondering if anyone has any neat ideas.

Comment: You could use runtime polymorphism if you set it up suitably and have a factory produce the desired concrete instance at runtime, but really... do you want this? First off, there's hardly any reason to use anything but `double`s (especially on x64), and the overhead to make this runtime-configurable would be such a waste.

Comment: Yeah I don't see how this is a good idea for anything beyond "It's cool what you can do."

Comment: Before you commit to anything, run some basic tests and compare the assembly. Chances are your floats are getting promoted to doubles right away anyway. And if you don't want `long double`s (which you shouldn't because those can't use all those fancy floating point registers we have nowadays), then why anything but `double`? And if you need Dramatic Precision (which I doubt), you can always use something like mpfr for special situations...

Comment: Yeah, I knew it was a silly idea and just followed the 'rule of cool', but I was interested if there was a way of switchign a type without having to do an inheritance hierarchy. Guess not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A float uses less memory than a double and is less precise.

BUT, there is only one set of math libraries and it is double based.  All floats get converted to double for calculations and then must be cast back to float.

Just use doubles.

Comment: Thanks. I'll just use MPFR if I get desperate!

Comment: @Cpt Ahab: You are certainly welcome to use MPFR for perfect precision, but would you mind sharing with us how you need that sort of precision in a _physics engine_? I was always under the impression that those things don't really depend all that much on precision (in fact, they often call for fixed-, not floating point arithmetic!!), so I'd be very curious to hear what you're doing!

Answer (score 2):

As @Kerrek SB points out, I'm not sure there's that much advantage to using `float`s over `double`s.

I can't say definitively without seeing your code, but you might be able to do what you want with templates.

```
template <typename T>
T Crunch1(T rhs)
{
    // do something with 'rhs' and return the result
}
template <typename T>
T Crunch2(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    // do something with 'lhs' & 'rhs' and return the result
}
```

This is still compile-time rather than runtime polymorphism but may be the closest thing to what you want.

And, you could create a series of plugins (one for each desired precision) and select that at runtime the way you suggest.  Each plugin would be an instantiation of the template code for a particular precision.  The combination of templates and a plugin architecture would give you the flexibility you want without the code duplication that you're obviously trying to avoid.

Comment: This is almost no different from just using the typedef... but you could now make those templated guys derived classes of some virtual base class. Supposing that all your code is formally the same, that would be the way to write it... oh well.

Comment: Templates are an alternate form of inheritance -- the chief advantage being that their use is checked at compile time (which avoids the possibility of a number of errors).  

I'm not sure I see the advantage of inheriting the templates from a base class ... or are you talking about the template parameters?

Comment: I was thinking of type erasure, the classical marriage of runtime and compile time polymorphism :-)